# Работа с QDateEdit и QTimeEdit c++

Tags: c++, qt

Как передать дату из QCalendarWidget в QDateEdit который находится на отдельном окне.

И как передать время из QTimeEdit в другой QTimeEdit на другом окне.
C++

Comment: Какой язык? c++, python, java, или не имеет значения? Добавьте метку языка в вопрос, нажав на кнопку `править`. Получить/поставить дату у календаря: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcalendarwidget.html#selectedDate-prop и получить/поставить дату QDateEdit: http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#date-prop. Передать время и дату, можно через сигнал, либо напрямую у объектов. Это касается всех виджетов

Comment: Язык программирования C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При выборе даты в `QCalendarWidget` генерится сигнал `void  clicked(const QDate &date)`, который надо связать со слотом `void   setDate(const QDate &date)` экземпляра `QDateEdit`. В принципе можно связать напрямую, если сохранять указатель на `QDateEdit` в этом самом окне, или сделать цепочку на подобии:

```
//окно  календарем
class Windows1{
    QCalendarWidget *calendar;
signals:
    void calendar_clicked(const QDate &date);
public:
    Windows1()
    {
        ....

        connect(calendar, SIGNAL(clicked(QDate)), this, SIGNAL(calendar_clicked(QDate)));
        ....
    }
}
//окно с едитом
class Windows2{
    QDateEdit *calendar;
signals:
    void calendar_clicked(const QDate &date);
public:
    Windows2()
    {
        ....

        connect(this, SIGNAL(calendar_clicked(QDate)), calendar, SLOT(setDate(QDate)));
        ....
    }
}
//родительское окно
class MainWindows{
    Windows1 *w1;
    Windows2 *w2;
public:
    MainWindows(){
        ...
        connect(w1, SIGNAL(calendar_clicked(QDate)), w2, SIGNAL(calendar_clicked(QDate)));
        ...
    }
}
```